# Вывести date() на php с произвольным смещением

Tags: php, дата

Подскажите как максимально коротко вывести на php

```
echo (date("d M Y в H:i"));
```

со случайным смещением в минутах от текущего времени, к примеру отнять 34 минуты?

Answer (score 2):

**time**

```
$time = time() - 34 * 60; // секунды
echo date('d M Y в H:i', $time);
```

**strtotime**

```
$time = strtotime('-34 minutes');
echo date('d M Y в H:i', $time);
```

**DateTime**

```
$date = new \DateTime('-34 minutes');
echo $date->format('d M Y в H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (date("d M Y в H:i", time()-34));
```