# Выбрать записи из базы, в которых update_time меньше 7 минут

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица `users_info` в которой есть ячейка **update_time**. В ней содержится время в UNIX *time()*

Мне нужно сделать SELECT который выдаст записи у которых *update_time* меньше 7-ми минут.

Вариант выбирать все записи а через php уже не выводить те которые не соответствуют условию - не подходит.

Какой вариант не подходит:

```
$users = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users_info` GROUP BY `update_time` DESC");
if ($users) while ($us = $users->fetch_assoc()) {
     $time = time()-$us['update_time'];
     $time = $time/60;
     if ($time < 7) {
        echo 'Выводим';
     }
}
```

Хотелось бы все это сделать в SELECT.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Если у вас поле `update_time` типа datetime, timestamp и аналогичное, то вы просто берете текущую дату [вычитаете время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526039/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-date-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) и в запросе говорите <= этому времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарии RifmaMan ссылка на ответы, где вычисление времени делается в php. А непосредственно в запросе можно

```
SELECT * FROM `users_info` 
   WHERE update_time > NOW()-INTERVAL 7 MINUTE  
   GROUP BY `update_time` DESC
```

а вашем коде вычисление временного интервала надо сделать так

```
$time = time() - strtotime($us['update_time']);
```